# Run 32bit application from a mapped drive under 64bit Windows?

Tags: vb6, 32bit-64bit, windows-7-x64

I have a 32-bit (VB6) application that has always been run (under 32bit Windows XP) from a networked drive so that multiple users can access it, and updates only need to be made in one place.

However, as we add (Windows 7) 64-bit machines to the network, I cannot find a way for these to run the application in 32-bit compatibility mode and keep it on the networked drive (although  I can do this for a local installation).

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why do you need to run in 32 bit compatibility mode?

I can run VB6 application fine from my Windows 7 64 bit machine from the local drive or a network drive (without any changes to the compatibility settings)

The only issue you might have is making sure the VB6 runtimes and whatever OCXs and ActiveX DLLs that are required are registered on the machine in question.

Answer (score 0):

"Run from network share" really isn't supported.  For one thing overlay actions result in high network traffic, and this can lead to timeouts or data errors causing program crashes.  For another many programs, especially those written in VB6, have dependencies that require local installation to work properly.

The AppCompat database is another player in your particular problem.  64-bit is probably much less of an issue than the fact you're moving beyond Windows XP.  Do you know which appcompat shims your program requires to run properly?  Often minor rewriting can avoid the need for most if not all of them.  The Application Compatibility Toolkit was designed to help you track these issues down.

See [Managing Shims in an Enterprise](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd837648%28WS.10%29.aspx), however I don't believe you can make Shim Database entries for programs that are not locally installed.